# Best Way to Transmit LARGE data packages via SOAP web service

Tags: wcf, soap, asmx

We are working with a .NET 3.5 app which is fast approaching legacy status.  We have an existing SOAP service which reads records from our database and saves them to a third party MS SQL database, sending all the data rows in a single batch.

This has always worked fine, but recently we've taken on a much larger client than any we've had before, and they are transmitting much larger batches, so much so that they have begun to fail.  We've upped the time out and max memory sizes in IIS, and maxed out the maxRequestLength in the web.config, but we are still bumping up against size problems.

So, I understand that long term, we should consider moving away from SOAP and into WCF, and plans for that are in the works.  But in the mean time, we need a short term fix for this new client.  And of course, to make the business and sales people happy, we need it kinda quickly.

I'm wondering what the best-practice approach might be.  Initially I'm thinking something like this, but I could be thinking inside the box too much:

1. Establish a bench mark of # of records over which we don’t want to attempt to sync all at once.
2. Before attempting to save the data, check the number of records against that bench mark
3. If it's above it, then break the transmission down into segments which are each below that benchmark.  SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM table WHERE sent = false, etc., if the benchmark is 10000.  Then update sent to true for those records once submitted. Repeat.
4. Obviously, this will slow the process down, so to handle the user experience, we may want to toss in a status bar so they can see the progress.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: When you say "SOAP", you mean "ASMX"? WCF can also do SOAP, and replaces ASMX.

Comment: .asmx. Yes, good question. I meant to say that but forgot.

Comment: WCF is also much more efficient at processing data. ASMX will sometimes keep three copies of the data in memory at the same time. WCF will even allow you to stream the data back to the client.

Comment: Understood.  So, I guess my question to you would be:  Is making the move from .asmx to WCF a fast process?  I'm not familiar with WCF.  I assume that the core logic which maps our data to their data would stay in place, but that the wrapper would change.  Correct?

Comment: That's largely correct. Assuming that your service isn't fancy, it's a very simple conversion.

Comment: Like I said, we know we need to move to WCF, but we also need a right-now kind of fix on this.  Is moving this to WCF a right-now fix?

Comment: That's largely correct. Assuming that your service isn't fancy, it's a very simple conversion. If you need to remain bit-for-bit compatible with existing code, then you can tell WCF to use the older XmlSerializer that you are currently using with ASMX.

Comment: Ok, so start with a google search on "convert .asmx to wcf" ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments from John, you should consider if you are solving the problem in the most optimal way.

It looks like you are triggering a one way sync between 2 database by calling a web service. This approach leads to the time out and memory problems that you are experiencing.

If your goal is to do the one way sync, you could use a free framework such as Microsofts sync framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/sync